# (Filtering w/ JS) Why does "#" not work while everything else in the alphabet does

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, algorithm, filter

So, I was retrieving elements from another webpage and was attempting to make an organized list out of them that, when a letter was clicked, would hide all titles except for the ones whose single-letter generated classes matched.

My Problem; This worked well for all of them except for the '#' class, which is designated to those elements whose starting letters are not A-Z (i.e. "3", ".", "/", etc.). Notice how when you click the "#" in the snippet, it will either display all of them (if it is hit first) and display an error, or will just display an error. Why does that, and only that, not work.

I have duplicated the issue with jsfiddle here, replacing all of my php functionality with imitations (the program itself is not this useless, this is just to isolate the issue). The original post I made was probably way too intimidating, with a slew of scattered but relevant php scripts including a dom reader, so this makes it easier and more relevant:

## Steps to reproduce

- Click on the "Click Here" button
- Click on the `#`, the first item on the list

## Expected beahvior:

- Sub items should show next to `#` (`#1 #2 #3`)

## Actual behavior:

- A JS error occurs: `jquery-1.10.2.js:1850 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .#`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   pelement = 0;
   a = "#ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; i = 0;
   while(i<27){
      $("#letters").append("<li onclick='letShow(this);' class='"
         +a[i]+"'>"+a[i]+"</li>");
      $("#selection").append(
         "<li class='"+a[i]+"'>"+a[i]+"1</li>"+
         "<li class='"+a[i]+"'>"+a[i]+"2</li>"+
         "<li class='"+a[i]+"'>"+a[i]+"3</li>");
      i+=1;
   }
});

function displayToggle(element) {
   $("#"+element).css("display", (($("#"+element).css("display") == "none")?"block":"none"));
}
function letShow(element) {
   if(pelement == "0" || pelement == element ||
      $("#selection").css("display") == "none") 
         displayToggle('selection');
   $("#selection li").not("."+$(element).attr("class")).hide();
   $("."+$(element).attr("class")).show();
   pelement = element;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type:none; 
  display:none;
  float:left;
}

/*Just to achieve fixed positioning*/
#anchor { 
    float: left;
    position: relative;
} #anchor div {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 15px 0 0 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<div onClick='displayToggle("letters");'>Click Here</div>
<ul id="letters"></ul>
<div id="anchor"><div><ul id="selection"></ul></div></div>
```

Comment: Please add a better explanation of "actual behavior" vs "expected behavior".

Comment: Run the snippet. You will see that clicking the "#" breaks it whereas everything else successfully displays the expected set of `li`s.

Comment: I ran the snippet, I'm trying to help you write better questions. What you wrote as a comment should always be within your post.

Comment: Yeah. Figured that out in hind sight and edited. Thanks

Comment: Look at my edit and notice how much easier it is to understand what you are asking. You don't even really need your paragraphs above since you have a nice running example of the problem

Comment: I'll be sure to keep all of that in mind next time I ask / answer something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape `#` when putting them in a selector. Look for the line that says

```
var escapedClassName = $(element).attr("class").replace('#', '\\#');
```

See https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ and https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar").

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   pelement = 0;
   a = "#ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; i = 0;
   while(i<27){
      $("#letters").append("<li onclick='letShow(this);' class='"+a[i]+"'>"+a[i]+"</li>");
      $("#selection").append(
         "<li class='"+a[i]+"'>"+a[i]+"1</li>"+
         "<li class='"+a[i]+"'>"+a[i]+"2</li>"+
         "<li class='"+a[i]+"'>"+a[i]+"3</li>");
      i+=1;
   }
});

function displayToggle(element) {
   $("#"+element).css("display", (($("#"+element)  
      .css("display") == "none")?"block":"none"));
}
function letShow(element) {
   if(pelement == "0" || pelement == element ||   
      $("#selection").css("display") == "none") 
         displayToggle('selection');
   var escapedClassName = $(element).attr("class").replace('#', '\\#');
   $("#selection li").not("."+escapedClassName).hide();
   $("."+escapedClassName).show();
   pelement = element;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type:none; 
  display:none;
  float:left;
}

#anchor { 
    float: left;
    position: relative;
} #anchor div {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 15px 0 0 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<div onClick='displayToggle("letters");'>Click Here</div>
<ul id="letters"></ul>
<div id="anchor"><div><ul id="selection"></ul></div></div>
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot. I would not have figured that out for a while without that.

Comment: @MoMN Since I'm all over your post already... You could have figured it out. Be sure to look for errors in your console, it was telling you what the problem was: `jquery-1.10.2.js:1850 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .#`